# Modify Data From Child To Parent

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to modify a property `routing` of a parent component from a child as follows:

```
//- Parent
<template>
    <First @toggleContent="routing = !routing" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return { routing: true }
  }
}
</script>

//- Child (First component)
<template>
 <div>
  <i class="bx bx-shape-triangle" @click="toggleContent()"></i>
   {{routing}}
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
props: {
    routing: Boolean
},
methods: {
    toggleContent() {
        this.$emit('toggleContent')
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

on the console does not mark me any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child component requires a prop `routing` that needs to passed in from parent component, also keep in mind [always using kebab case for your events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

```
<First @toggle-content="routing = !routing" :routing="routing"/>
```

Modify your event name in `emit` as well:

```
toggleContent() {
  this.$emit('toggle-content')
}
```